# Relaciones de tablas en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una gran duda acerca de las relaciones en mysql. Verán, estoy creando un sitio que se parezca a un e-commerce, es para un colega.

Estoy creando una tabla llamada **categorias** y otra llamada **subcategorias**. En la tabla **subcategorias** tengo una columna llamada `categoria_id`, la cual contendrá la ID de la categoría seleccionada. Entonces así, podre mostrar las subcategorias con sus categorias respectivas.

**Un ejemplo:** Accesorios para celulares ( categoría ) , Cargadores (subcategoria) y así sucesivamente.

¿Es necesario crear una relación entre la ID de la categoría, y el categoria_id de la tabla "subcategorias"? espero haberme explicado correctamente.

Saludos.

Comment: Pues la relación ya esta, ahora si te refieres a que si debe de crear la referencia a nivel de llave foránea con su constraint, pues depende de cada quien, muchos te dirán que la mejor practica es que si.

Comment: Si, deberias hacer esa relacion y tambien un id de subcategorias con identity 1-1 (el cual va a ir incrementandose cada vez que agregues un item a esa tabla)

Comment: Lo que yo había hecho anteriormente fue, crear una category_id en la tabla "categorías" la cual sea primaria y autoincrementable, luego, en la tabla subcategorias, había creado también una columna category_id, que sea primaria pero NO autoincrementable, entonces hacía la relación de category_id (categoría) con category_id (subcategorias)

Comment: Lo lógico sería que subcategorías tuviera un id propio autoincrementable y un categoría_id para relacionar con categorías

Comment: No quiero armar más lío Juance, las respuestas que te dieron fueron adecuadas a tu pregunta, pero el modelo que pienas definir solo te permitiría dos niveles de jerarquía, no podrías tener por ejemplo `Accesorios para celulares -> Cargadores -> Iphone`?

Comment: Podría ser. Pero, tendría que crear otra relación, no? que la tabla subcategorias se relacione con ID de modelos?

Comment: No exactamente, lo que pregunto es si podés llegar a tener un modelo  de clasificación de productos que tenga más de dos niveles, otro ejemplo sería:  Celulares -> Accesorios -> Fundas.

Comment: Ah, si, se podría. De hecho ahora mismo lo estoy haciendo. Tengo una categoría, una subcategoría y el modelo del producto, en caso de que éste llevase uno (véase en celulares, o productos de marca)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Si por *necesario* quieres decir *obligatorio*, la respuesta es **no**, es decir, puedes crear dos tablas y que ellas aunque compartan información, no tengan ninguna relación entre si.

Sin embargo, es **extremadamente aconsejable** que **SI** establezcas una relación entre ambas y cuides la [Integridad Referencial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integridad_referencial) de tus datos, ya que de no hacerlo sería técnicamente posible insertar datos de **subcategorías** que no tuvieran una **categoría** existente.

Te paso la documentación de MySQL sobre las [Foreign Keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

**EDITADO**: Te paso un ejemplo que impedirá que puedas tener una **subcategoría** sin un padre **categoría**.

```
CREATE TABLE categoria (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    nom_categoria VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE sub_categoria(
    id INT,
    nom_subcategoria VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    categoria_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (categoria_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (categoria_id)
        REFERENCES categoria(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: Usando este ejemplo me fue posible poder crear la relación y entender más sobre las relaciones. Creo que mi duda ya está solucionada. He hecho la relación correctamente, el engine que uso es InnoDB.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto @juance . Para futuras preguntas, si indicas el engine las respuestas podrán ser más específicas. Saludos.

Comment: No estaría de acuerdo con "ya que de no hacerlo sería técnicamente posible insertar datos de subcategorías que no tuvieran una categoría existente".. es solo técnicamente posible si abris la base de datos a mano y metes los datos.. si hay un sistema adelante, si no diseñas un formulario de carga para ello, debería ser imposible, porque categoría (en la tabla subcategoria) debería ser not null y tu sistema no dejar cargar subcategorias sin categorias... igual +1

Answer (score 7):

> ### NUEVA RESPUESTA: UNA SOLUCIÓN MUCHO MÁS SIMPLE

La verdad que me sorprendió la respuesta de @PatricioMoracho la cual me ayudó a reconsiderar **una solución del problema mucho más simple de comprender y mantener**. Su respuesta me abrió los ojos sobre una limitación importante del modelo anterior: ¡la posibilidad de categorías y sub-categorías anidadas!.

Curiosamente, plantearse tal complejidad puede llevarnos a resolver el problema de una forma muy sencilla. Suele ocurrir que en la vida, lo que es complicado nos ayuda a ver que *hay un camino más simple*.

Veamos:

En efecto, **se puede tener una sola tabla `categorias`** a la cual vamos a añadir una nueva columna llamada `padre_id`. En esa columna pondremos el id del padre de cada categoría. Si es una categoría principal, pondremos ese valor en cero (`0`). Eso nos ayudará a recuperar las categorías principales solamente, si así lo deseamos...

El código presenta una consulta sencilla que mostrará cada categoría y al lado sus hijos.

Evidentemente, se podrían hacer consultas más complejas, como alguna que muestre cada categoría y sus sub-categorías por niveles, o código que llegue a la categoría *abuelo* por medio de su categoría padre.

#### `Código:` <kbd>[`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/BBKE65784)</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS categorias 
    (
      categoria_id          INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      categoria_nombre      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      padre_id              INT NOT NULL

    );


INSERT INTO categorias (categoria_nombre, padre_id) 
            VALUES  
            ('Teléfonos',0),
            ('Celulares',1),
            ('Accesorios para celulares',2),
            ('Baterías',3),
            ('Protectores',3),
            ('Manos libres',3),
            ('Computadoras',0),
            ('Computadoras de Escritorio',7),
            ('Computadoras Portátiles',7),
            ('Teclado',8),
            ('Monitor',8),
            ('Mouse',8),                
            ('Funda de portátil',9);                

SELECT c.categoria_nombre as padre, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(hijos.categoria_nombre SEPARATOR ",") AS hijos     
       FROM categorias c
       INNER JOIN categorias hijos 
          ON c.categoria_id=hijos.padre_id    
       GROUP BY hijos.padre_id;
```

#### `Resultado:`

```
    padre                        hijos
1   Teléfonos                    Celulares
2   Celulares                    Accesorios para celulares
3   Accesorios para celulares    Baterías,Protectores,Manos libres
4   Computadoras                 Computadoras de Escritorio,Computadoras Portátiles
5   Computadoras de Escritorio   Teclado,Monitor,Mouse
6   Computadoras Portátiles      Funda de portátil
```

---

> @deprecated
>   Esta es una respuesta antigua

Lo que se suele hacer en estos casos es algo como esto.

**Nota:** Se trata de un **ejemplo básico**. Faltaría añadirle en la creación de tabla la clave foránea, integridad  referencial, índices, según el tipo de base de datos (InnoDB, MyISAM).

Visto que estás empezando, y algunos han cuestionado que en mi respuesta no he puesto nada sobre la *integridad referencial*, quiero indicarte que antes de seguir adelante es importante decidir el tipo de *engine*  que tendrán tus tablas.

En MySQL existen dos: `MyISAM` e `InnoDB`. Ambos tienen sus ventajas y sus desventajas. Por ejemplo este artículo (y otros) pueden orientarte: [¿MyISAM o InnoDB? Elige tu motor de almacenamiento MySQL](https://blog.arsys.es/myisam-o-innodb-elige-tu-motor-de-almacenamiento-mysql/)

Puedes consultar también la documentación oficial de MySQL (en inglés):

- [MyISAM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html)
- [InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-storage-engine.html)

El código presenta un ejemplo básico y una consulta que funcionaría en el caso de que quieras obtener las sub_categorías de una categoría x.

Si te decides por `InnoDB` recomiendo que leas la documentación de dicho engine, y cómo funciona la sintaxis de creación de tablas, cómo se indican las claves primarias, la referencias, los `on delete`, los `on update`... etc. Es un tema mucho más amplio que establecer una simple relación. Según configures los `on delete`  por ejemplo, los datos hijos se borrarán al borrar al padre, para no dejar datos huérfanos. Es necesario informarse sobre cómo funciona antes de implementarlo...

#### `Código:` [`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/LLHVE91931)

```
/*
-- ATENCIÓN NO USE DROP TABLE CON SUS TABLAS REALES
-- YA QUE DROP TABLE BORRARÁ SUS DATOS
-- DROP TABLE SE USA AQUÍ SÓLO PARA PODER PROBAR LOS DATOS */ 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS categorias;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sub_categorias;



/* NO COPIE LA SENTENCIA ^ DROP TABLE ^ EN SUS DATOS REALES */



CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS categorias 
    (
      categoria_id          INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      categoria_nombre      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    );


CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS sub_categorias 
    (
      subcategoria_id          INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      subcategoria_nombre      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      categoria_id             INT (10)  
    );



INSERT INTO categorias (categoria_nombre) 
            VALUES  ('Accesorios para celulares'), ('Accesorios PC');

INSERT INTO sub_categorias (subcategoria_nombre,categoria_id) 
            VALUES  
            ('Baterías', 1),
            ('Protectores', 1),
            ('Manos libres', 1),
            ('Teclado', 2),
            ('Monitor', 2),
            ('Mouse', 2)                
            ;   


SELECT  subcategoria_nombre FROM  sub_categorias sc
INNER JOIN categorias c 
ON sc.categoria_id=c.categoria_id
WHERE sc.categoria_id=1;
```

#### `Resultado`

```
    subcategoria_nombre
1   Baterías
2   Protectores
3   Manos libres
```

Comment: Uf, la verdad que agradezco muchísimo tu respuesta asi como también la respuesta de todos los usuarios que se han tomado el tiempo de resolver mi duda. Tenía un gran lío con las relaciones. Me conviene hacer la relación en mysql, o hacerlo directamente mediante código?.

Comment: @A.Cedano ¿No te parece que cometes un grave fallo de diseño?, ¿que te impide introducir los valores `('Carcasa', 333)` en tu tabla de `sub_categorias `? Por favor establece la relación.

Comment: @Juance eso depende de si tu bd estará en InnoDB o en MyIsam. En el primer caso podrás indicar las llaves foráneas directamente en el `CREATE TABLE...` en el segundo, el concepto de llave foránea no existe, lo cual no quiere decir que las relaciones no funcionen... de hecho, el ejemplo muestra que funcionan. Recomiendo que leas sobre las ventajas y desventajas entre InnoDB y MyIsam, pues el primer paso es decidirte por cuál de los dos usar. Sin eso, responder a otras preguntas tendrá poco sentido.

Comment: @DavidIsla te ruego que no intentes buscarle la quinta pata al gato, como ocurrió ayer precisamente con una pregunta sobre las _relaciones_. Lee el encabezado de la respuesta y mi comentario al OP anterior a este. He puesto un ejemplo básico, si consideras que se le debe dar todo hecho sin siquiera saber si usará InnoDB o MyISAM, puedes editar tu pregunta y darle un ejemplo completo, con todo hecho, en los dos sistemas. O darle la posibilidad de que evalúe cuál de los dos debe usar y que investigue al respecto. La pregunta no iba sobre **integridad referencial**.

Comment: @DavidIsla Lo cortes no quita lo valiente. Creo que la respuesta es clara y la integridad si bien es necesaria, no es parte de la duda principal, pero si se recomienda en la respuesta.

Comment: @A.Cedano te confundes si crees que voy buscando problemas donde no los hay. Tranquilo que me cuidaré de no opinar más sobre tus respuestas.

Comment: @RafaelAngelRamirezEstrada yo así lo había entendido con _¿Es necesario crear una relación_ pero como veo que sólo lo entendí yo así, me callo.

Comment: Si el OP decide usar MyISAM, la integridad referencial no podría aplicar, así que no tiene ningún sentido ofrecer una respuesta tratando ese tema, más aún cuando la duda era sobre si debía relacionar ambas tablas, no sobre **cómo** relacionarlas. Ahora él debe decidir qué engine MySQL usar y hacer el diseño de las tablas en consecuencia.

Comment: @RafaelAngelRamirezEstrada _la integridad si bien es necesaria, no es parte de la duda principal, pero si se recomienda en la respuesta._ Sí o no. Ya que la integridad referencial dependerá de si el OP se decide por InnoDB o por MyISAM. Supongo que sabrás que MyISAM **no contempla integridad referencial**.

Comment: @DavidIsla Apoyo tu comentario y retiro lo dicho. Entendí mal la pregunta . Es bueno comentar, no lo dejes de hacer. Pero como dice A.Cedano esta es una comunidad para construir. Si tienes buenas razónes para agregar y mejorar la respuesta adelante. A todos nos sirve.

Comment: @A.Cedano No lo sabia, por eso estoy en esta comunidad, para aprender. Gracias por tus comentarios.

Comment: @RafaelAngelRamirezEstrada SOes es muy grande y no tengo necesidad, si quiero explicar algo pongo una respuesta o se lo haré saber directamente al OP. Todo está ok por mi parte.

Comment: Cedano, tu código es muy muy bueno, y las ideas que me has dado me están sirviendo de muchísimo. Como no se me ocurrió antes que la tabla categorías podría contener un elemento padre, quizá con el lío que vengo teniendo en el cabeza jajaja. Muchísimas gracias y lo pondré en práctica.

Pero hay algo más, que me tiene en duda y es, que cada producto tendrá su marca (Adidas, Nike, etc). Dichas marcas me hubiera gustado tenerlas todas en una tabla, y al momento de crear un producto, poder elegir la Categoría, con su hijo subcategoria y la marca.

Comment: @Juance en ese caso estaríamos hablando de **otras dos tablas aparte de la tabla `categorias`**, las cuales serían más o menos: `marcas (id_marca,marca...)` y `productos (id_producto, id_marca, id_categoria...)` en la tabla `productos` el campo `id_categoria` podría ser cualquier categoría, la que corresponda a ese producto. Si es una categoría hija... o nieta, puedes ascender al padre y al abuelo mediante código SQL. Pero esa sería ya otra pregunta.

Answer (score 4):

Juance, ya te han respondido tu pregunta, tanto la respuesta de A. Cedano como la de David Isla son válidas. El tema es que noté una limitación en el modelo que tu mismo estabas proponiendo que es el de categoría / subcategoría, y te consulté sobre eso. Básicamente solo puedes manejar dos niveles, no podrías "colgar" una subcategoría de otra subcategoría, y en general solo dos niveles de catalogación suele ser poco, basta ver sitios como mercadolibre u otros. Mi propuesta es manejar una única tabla `categorias` sin distinción lo cual en cierto modo es razonable ya que todas son categorías y lo que cambia es la jerarquía de como las queremos ver, que se manejarán por un atributo `nodo`. Si en algún momento necesitamos cambiar de lugar algo o directamente crear un nuevo nivel para todas las categorías, este modelo es más flexible. **Tiene una complicación importante**: te tienes que hacer cargo de la actualización del `nodo`, no es complejo pero tiene su lógica.

Extiendo un poco el ejemplo de A.Cedano para que lo veas:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS categorias;

CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS categorias 
    (
      categoria_id          INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      nodo                  VARCHAR(40),
      categoria_nombre      VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
    );


INSERT INTO categorias (categoria_nombre, nodo) 
    VALUES  ('Categorias de Productos', '0001'), 
            ('Accesorios para celulares', '00010001'), 
            ('Celulares', '00010002'),
            ('Accesorios PC', '00010003'),
            ('Baterías', '000100010001'),
            ('Protectores', '000100010002'),
            ('Plásticos', '0001000100020001'),
            ('Vidrio', '0001000100020001'),
            ('Manos libres', '000100010003'),
            ('Teclado', '000100020001'),
            ('Monitor', '000100020001'),
            ('Mouse', '000100020001'),                
            ('Gama Alta', '000100020001'),
            ('Iphone 6', '0001000200010001'),
            ('Samsung S8', '0001000200010002'),
            ('Gama Media', '000100020002'),
            ('Gama Baja', '000100020002')
            ;   


SELECT  c1.nodo, 
        CONCAT(SPACE(LENGTH(c1.nodo)-LENGTH(c.nodo)),  c1.categoria_nombre) AS 'categoria_nombre'
    FROM categorias c
    INNER JOIN categorias c1
        ON LEFT(c1.nodo, LENGTH(c.nodo)) = c.nodo
    WHERE c.categoria_id = 1
    ORDER BY c1.nodo
```

La salida sería algo así:

```
nodo             categoria_nombre
================ =====================================
0001             Categorias de Productos
00010001             Accesorios para celulares
000100010001             Baterías
000100010002             Protectores
0001000100020001             Plásticos
0001000100020001             Vidrio
000100010003             Manos libres
00010002             Celulares
000100020001             Gama Alta
0001000200010001             Iphone 6
0001000200010002             Samsung S8
000100020002             Gama Media
000100020002             Gama Baja
00010003             Accesorios PC
000100030001             Teclado
000100030001             Monitor
000100030001             Mouse
```

La identación es solo para visualizar la jerarquía. Cada producto tendría una `categoria_id` relacionado con la tabla `categorias` que apuntaría al nivel predefinido dentro del árbol. La búsqueda de productos por debajo de una determinada categoría es muy fácil de implementar, por ejemplo si quieres todos los Accesorios para celulares, solo tienes que indicar a la consulta anterior el `categoria_id = 2`. El mantenimiento del `nodo` si eventualmente vas a crear un ABM para el mismo no es complicado pero hay que ser cuidadoso, una estructura así es más fácil si el mantenimiento se hace por script.

En el ejemplo que te estoy proponiendo, cada rama o nodo podría albergar hasta 9999 categorías, y hasta 10 niveles, pero eso es fácilmente extensible modificando el campo `nodo` y la lógica de actualización. Un modelo algo más avanzado sería manejar unas tablas adicionales `jerarquia` y `categoria_jerarquia` para eventualmente administrar distintos modelos jerárquicos que dependan de algún criterio, por ejemplo "categorias simples" o "categorias extendidas" pero no te quiero complicar la vida, tal vez este modelo te sirva.

#### Información adicional: ¿Como agregamos más categorías?

Primero que nada, recomiendo mantener una primer categoría principal base en el primer nivel, en el ejemplo "Categorias de Productos", cualquier nuevo ítem debe ir siempre debajo de la misma, esto simplemente por que luego resulta mas sencillo la lógica para manejar las inserciones. Veamos un ejemplo: supongamos que queremos agregar un nuevo accesorio para celulares "Cargadores", ¿como lo hacemos?

- En primer lugar hay que establecer cual va a ser la categoría padre, en este ejemplo será "Accesorios para celulares", en la consulta que armé, no estoy mostrando el ID pero todas las categorías tienen un id, la de los Accesorios es la 2, haciendo lo siguiente obtendremos el nodo "padre" y la longitud del mismo

  ```
  SELECT nodo AS NodoPadre,
          LENGTH(NODO) As LongitudNodoPadre
          FROM categorias
          WHERE categoria_id = 2 ;
  ```
- El nodo "padre" es `00010001` el nuevo ítem lo vamos a insertar debajo de este y al final de las categorías de esa rama por lo que necesitamos calcular el nodo final que sería algo así `00010001????`, para calcular justamente la parte de `????` simplemente tenemos que ver cual es el último nodo de esa rama y sumarle uno, así:

  ```
  SELECT  CONCAT('00010001',RIGHT(CAST((10000 + CAST(MAX(right(nodo,4)) AS UNSIGNED ) + 1) AS CHAR(5)),4))
     FROM categorias
      WHERE nodo LIKE '00010001%'
            AND LENGTH(nodo) = 12;
  ```
- Estamos viendo la rama debajo del nodo padre, esto por el `LIKE '00010001%'`y además por que verificamos que la longitud del nodo sea 4 + la longitud del nodo padre mediante `LENGTH(nodo) = 12`. El resultado sería: `000100010004`, si ves la rama:

  ```
  nodo            categoria_nombre
  =============== ===================
  000100010001    Baterías
  000100010002    Protectores
  000100010003    Manos libres
  ```

  Queda claro que deberemos insertar la nueva categoría como:

  ```
  INSERT INTO categorias (categoria_nombre, nodo) 
          VALUES  ('Cargadores', '000100010004'),
  ```

Con este modelo, las inserciones son siempre en el último nivel de la rama, eventualmente se podrían armar la lógica para reordenar los items de manera secuencial, haciendo un "intercambio" del nodo entre ítems, en cuanto a los `delete`, es conveniente que sean lógicos, usando por ejemplo un `FlagHabilitado` (1/0) pero eventualmente también podrían ser físicos.

Comment: Tu respuesta me sorprendió muchísimo, dado a que nunca se me había ocurrido algo similar a eso. Es un código muy optimizado y una idea muy buena. Lo voy a aplicar, por el momento tengo 3 o 4 tablas que se relacionan entre sí para poder crear categorías, subcategorias y tipos de productos con sus modelos, es algo muy liado pero lo estoy haciendo. Mirando tu ejemplo, la verdad que me quedó muy claro que estás tratando de explicar, así que voy a ponerlo a prueba. Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Pero tengo una gran duda. Por ejemplo, si quiero crear una categoría, como le indico el número único que va a tener ese nodo? ( por ejemplo el 0004 )

Comment: La inteligencia ahí pasa a estar en la aplicación. Si agregas una categoría en función de quién es la categoría padre tienes que ver si tiene hijos, si es así obtienes el Máximo de los últimos 4 caracteres de los nodos hijos y sumas uno. Si puedo, mañana complemento un poco la respuesta con algún ejemplo de alta, ordenamiento o borrado.

Comment: Siguiendo tu ejemplo, me maree un poco pero al fin logré entender como hacer las inserciones de nuevas categorías. ¿Podrías ponerme un ejemplo de como sería para hacer un delete? porque pienso que simplemente borrar la columna no sería preciso. Muchísimas gracias por la explicación y todos los ejemplos.

Comment: Un delete físico es tan solo un `DELETE categorias WHERE categoría_id=??`,  va a queda un "hueco" entre nodos pero es no trae ninguna complicación. Un delete lógico, sería tener un campo `FlagHabilitado`  en `categorias` y siempre lees aquellas cuyo `FlagHabilitado` es 1 (en cualquier consulta), para borrar lógicamente o más bien deshabilitar harías un `UPDATE categorias SET FlagHabiltado=0` WHERE categoria_id = ??`

Comment: @Juance, es una propuesta sorprendente y válida. Pero me parece bastante complicada de entender y de mantener. Si se quiere flexibilidad, se podría replantear el modelo original con una sola tabla. (Ver mi respuesta editada).

Comment: @A. Cedano, yo uso bastante este modelo para manejar jerarquías por lo que me resulta natural, es cierto que es complejo de entender el manejo si hay que armar un ABM, pero resulta mucho más simple con jerarquías que tienen poco movimiento, es decir, donde se crean y se modifican poco y nada. Sería bueno e interesante que presentes tu modelo, Saludos.

Comment: Ya lo he hecho @PatricioMoracho en mi respuesta  editada. De hecho, propongo un modelo bastante simple de entender y de mantener, tanto para categorías con mucho o poco movimiento.

Comment: @A.Cedano, no había visto tu última edición... Esta perfecto, solo de exquisito, eventualmente le agregaría el atributo de `nodo` u `orden` para poder fijar el orden dentro de cada rama, sino estamos obligados a depender de `categoria_id` para ordenar y no nos sirve cuando queramos agregar una nueva categoría en una determinada posición.

Comment: @Patricio Moracho Hola, cómo puedo obtener las categorías de la tabla izquierda con los nodos. ejemplo: imaginemos que estoy en la categoría, protectores para celulares y quiero obtener todas las categorías padre de esa subcategoria.

Answer (score 0):

De alguna manera con la estructura que estás planteando ya tenes una relación entre **categorias** y **subcategorias**, pero esta es una mera referencia no es físicamente en la base de datos.

Considero **peligroso** usar sin una relación física porque la base de datos no te gestionará la **[`integridad referencial`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integridad_referencial)**, además no se creará un **indice** a ese campo **`concepto_id`** que declaraste y en un futuro te puede crear problemas de rendimiento en operaciones de consultas y actualizaciones si utilizas esa columna como criterio.

En resumen no es necesario, pero asumes riegos innecesarios que debes cubrir desde la programación.

Recomiendo realizar una lectura sobre las [`llaves primarias`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp) y [`llaves foráneas`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) antes que todo para comprender mejor.

Comment: Las columnas, para hacer una relación, deben de ser primarias, o que atributo deben llevar dichas columnas?. Por ejemplo, establecería una relación entre category_id (categorías) y category_id (subcategorias)

Comment: @Juance Te recomiendo realizar esas lecturas que te mencioné para comprender mejor las relaciones. Saludos!

Comment: sisi, en eso estoy, muchas gracias por facilitarme la documentación. Gracias a todos los que se tomaron el tiempo de responder.