# Relacionar 3 tablas en mysql con restricciones

Tags: mysql

Tengo 4 tablas, unas imagenes, unas categorías y unos atributos para cada categoria. El caso es que necesito una cuarta tabla que me relacione para cada imagen un atributo para una categoría, pero como máximo un atributo de cada categoría.

### Imagenes

ImagenID
NombreImagen

### Categorias

CategoriaID
NombreCategoria

### Atributos

AtributoID
CategoriaID
NombreAtributo

y una última tabla que relaciona las imágenes con una categoría y un atributo de los de esa categoría

### ImagenesCategoria

ImagenID
CategoriaID
AtributoID

Cada imagen solo puede tener un atributo de una categoría dada, con lo cual ImagenID y CategoriaID serían la clave.

La duda que tengo es que realmente CategoriaID me sobraría de la tabla de ImagenesCategoria, ya que va implícita en AtributoID.

Tengo 2 opciones:
-Dejar CategoriaID, con lo cual podría meter un AtributoID y CategoriaID que no se corresponderían con los de la tabla Atributos

-Quitar CategoriaID, en este caso como podría hacer para no meter en ImagenesCategoria dos Atributos de la misma Categoría

Para que quede más claro pongo un ejemplo:

### Categorias

1 color
2 forma

### Imagenes

34 triangulo-amarillo.jpg
35 circulo-rojo.jpg

### Atributos

1 1 rojo
2 1 verde
3 1 amarillo
4 2 cuadrado
5 2 círculo
6 2 triángulo

### ImagenesCategoria

34 1 3 ---> sería amarillo
34 2 6 ---> sería triángulo
35 1 1 ----> rojo
35 2 5 ---->círculo

Lo que quiero evitar es poner más de un color a una imagen o poner para la categoria color algo que no sea de la categoría por ejemplo (círculo, cuadrado)

Comment: Tu solución está bien, solo debes poner atributoid como "unique" para que no se pueda usar más de una vez ese atributo...

Comment: Tu solución está bien, solo debes poner atributoid como "unique" para que no se pueda usar más de una vez ese atributo...

Comment: Parece que lo que quieres es que alguien te haga el trabajo. Aporta lo que has intentado. **Te recomiendo que leas [ask]** y que completes el [tour] para más información.

Comment: Pero aun así podría meter una combinación AtributoID CategoriaID que no existiera en la tabla Atributos.

Comment: @Spidvmp gracias!, puedes usar [ ask ] y [ tour ] (sin espacios), para que automáticamente aparezcan los enlaces!

Comment: no entiendo que quieres decir "parece que lo que quieres es que alguien te haga el trabajo". Tengo una duda sobre diseño de bases de datos y la posteo para que alguien con más conocimientos u otra visión difetente me pueda aclarar la duda. El trabajo ya lo tengo resuelto por software, solo quería saber si alguien tenía alguna idea de hacerlo directamente mediante el diseño de la base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Algunas cosas no quedan claras en tu diseño... Mi respuesta está orientada a enfocar el problema desde otro punto de vista.

Considero que los tres elementos: `imagenes, categorias, atributos` pueden existir por separado en sendas tablas.

Si se trata de asignar categorías y atributos a imágenes, entonces podríamos implementar una cuarta tabla que gestione las relaciones. En cada fila de esa tabla habrá entonces un elemento descriptivo completo de cada imagen.

Ahora bien... yo he agregado a propósito una imagen con id `5`, para ilustrar que tu diseño podría aún perfeccionarse... pero sin conocimiento profundo del contexto no puedo darte más sugerencias.

### Código

<kbd>**[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/SLRVE63921)**</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS imagenes_20171025 
(
    imagen_id   INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    imagen_nom  VARCHAR(150)

)ENGINE=INNODB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categorias_20171025 (
    categoria_id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    categoria_nom VARCHAR(150) 
)ENGINE=INNODB;  


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS atributos_20171025 (
    atributo_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    atributo_nom VARCHAR(150) 
)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS imagenes_categorias_atributos_20171025 (
    imagen_id INT, 
    categoria_id INT, 
    atributo_id INT, 
    UNIQUE KEY (imagen_id, categoria_id, atributo_id) ,
     FOREIGN KEY fk_img (imagen_id)    REFERENCES imagenes_20171025   (imagen_id)    ON DELETE CASCADE,
     FOREIGN KEY fk_cat (categoria_id) REFERENCES categorias_20171025 (categoria_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
     FOREIGN KEY fk_atr (atributo_id)  REFERENCES atributos_20171025  (atributo_id)  ON DELETE CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO imagenes_20171025 (imagen_nom)
    VALUES 
    ('triangulo-amarillo.jpg'),
    ('rombo-azul.jpg'),
    ('rombo-verde-mediano.jpg'),
    ('trapecio-mediano.jpg'),
    ('cuadrado-redondo????.jpg')
;

INSERT INTO categorias_20171025 (categoria_nom)
    VALUES 
    ('Color'),
    ('Forma'),
    ('Tamaño')
;    

INSERT INTO atributos_20171025 (atributo_nom)
    VALUES 
    ('Azul'),
    ('Amarillo'),
    ('Verde'),
    ('Mediano'),
    ('Redondo')
;

INSERT INTO imagenes_categorias_atributos_20171025 (imagen_id, categoria_id, atributo_id)
    VALUES 
    (1,1,2),
    (2,1,1),
    (3,1,3),
    (4,3,4),
    (5,2,5)
;


/*
SELECT * FROM imagenes_20171025;
SELECT * FROM categorias_20171025;
SELECT * FROM atributos_20171025;
SELECT * FROM atributos_20171025;
*/

SELECT 
    ica.imagen_id, ica.categoria_id, ica.atributo_id, 
    i.imagen_nom, c.categoria_nom, a.atributo_nom 
FROM imagenes_categorias_atributos_20171025 ica 
    LEFT JOIN imagenes_20171025 i ON ica.imagen_id=i.imagen_id 
    LEFT JOIN categorias_20171025 c ON ica.categoria_id=c.categoria_id 
    LEFT JOIN atributos_20171025 a ON ica.atributo_id=a.atributo_id 
ORDER BY i.imagen_id;
```

---

#### Resultado:

```
imagen_id   categoria_id    atributo_id imagen_nom                  categoria_nom   atributo_nom
1           1               2           triangulo-amarillo.jpg      Color           Amarillo
2           1               1           rombo-azul.jpg              Color           Azul
3           1               3           rombo-verde-mediano.jpg     Color           Verde
4           3               4           trapecio-mediano.jpg        Tamaño          Mediano
5           2               5           cuadrado-redondo????.jpg    Forma           Redondo
```

Comment: Efectivamente esto demuestra que la tabla de atributos no necesita el ID de categoría

Comment: Eso depende @amenadiel. La imagen con id `5` puesta a propósito quiere demostrar una posible laguna en el diseño. Sería interesante saber por ejemplo cuáles son las posibilidades de categorías atributos e incluso de imágenes. Por ejemplo: `triángulo, amarillo, grande` representa en realidad tres categorías: `forma, color y tamaño`. Me confunde que en imágenes tenga datos relativos a la forma (un triángulo aquí sería una *forma* o figura)... y que luego haya un atributo `forma`. Sin conocer más del contexto es difícil dar una respuesta acertada.

Comment: Si de todos modos, tenemos un `triangulo, amarillo, grande`... no se puede representar en una sola línea de la cuarta tabla, ya que habría que indicar dos categorías: `color` y `tamaño` y también dos atributos `amarillo` y `grande`. En la pregunta creí leer que quiere eso, que haya sólo una categoría por atributo... pero me parece que **ese deseo no se corresponde con la realidad**, porque precisamente una imagen podría tener varias categorías (`color, tamaño, forma`)  y respectivamente un atributo por cada una de esas categorías (`amarillo, grande, ¡triángulo!¿?`)

Comment: Ah bueno, pero el nombre de la imagen debiera ser dummy. La única integridad referencial a preservar es que una imagen no tenga dos valores para la misma categoría. Aunque, ahora que lo mencionas, también debiera tener una llave única en `(imagen_id,categoria_id)` puesto que la llave única que pusiste admite la coexistencia de (1,1,1) con (1,1,2)

Comment: Buen punto @amenadiel. Aunque me parece que tener dos llaves únicas así revela precisamente que el diseño debe ser pensando mejor.  Cuando leí la pregunta me acordé de [una pregunta planteada aquí hace un tiempo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/88081/29967)... y creo que en este caso las categorías podrían manejarse de esa manera. No es la respuesta aceptada en esa pregunta, pero me parece una solución válida y sencilla.

Comment: Ahora mismo mi opción de diseño sería añadir en Atributos la CategoriaID, para poder filtrar los atributos que corresponden a cada categoría. Después tengo decidido tener una tabla que relaciona ImagenID con AtributoID. Hay que tener en cuenta que una imagen no tiene porque tener un atributo de cada categoría, es decir podría tener un color pero no tener forma o tamaño. Como han dicho lo único sería mantener la integridad de forma que una imagen no pueda tener el atributo rojo y verde.

Comment: @LM esa es una posible solución. Ahora bien, si una imagen puede tener categoría Color, atributo Rojo y luego categoría Tamaño, atributo Mediano... Esa imagen no podrá ser representada como una entidad ubica en tu diseño. Tendría que haber dos filas con ese id imagen en la tabla que gestiona las relaciones. Lo cual es válido y factible. Podría ser la mejor opción o no, eso dependerá del contexto.

Comment: Ahora bien @L.M, si tú creas la tabla atributo con las columnas `atributo_id, categoria_id` y gestionas la relación con otra tabla usando `imagen_id, atributo_id` no vas a poder controlar que un elemento de imagen tenga varios colores, a no ser que coloques `imagen_id` como llave única en la tabla que gestiona las relaciones, en cuyo caso, una imagen no podrá jamás tener más de un atributo.

Comment: Voy a ensayar una respuesta visto que esto se convirtió en un hilo muy largo.

Comment: Te agradezco @A.Cedano la ayuda recibida, es la primera vez que posteo aquí y da gusto ver como se vuelca la gente en ayudar. Como bien dices con mi solución propuesta no puedo controlar que para una imagen se le puedan añadir dos atributos de la misma categoría (ej. color rojo y color azul). Y con la otra solución que había pensado (añadiendo la categoria a la tabla que relaciona imagenes con atributos y pondíendo como llave única imagenID y categoriaID, se me resuelve este problema, pero me aparece que puedo crear una fila en esta tabla que incluya un imagen con color grande...

Comment: la única solución que encuentro es controlar por programación a la hora de añadir a la tabla de las relaciones, que no se inserte para una imagen un atributo de una categoría de la cual ya habías insertado antes.

Answer (score 0):

Convengamos en que el problema puede explicarse con tres postulados:

- Se desea mantener una colección de imágenes en donde cada imagen tenga una cantidad N de atributos cuyo significado es libre: tamaño, color, alias, peso, ancho, alto, transparencia, temática, autor (funciona como ponerle tags a la imagen)
- Una imagen no puede tener dos veces el mismo atributo. (no tiene sentido que tenga dos colores ni dos alias)
- Cada atributo de una cierta imagen no puede tener más que un valor.

Entonces tendríamos una tabla de imágenes en donde cada imagen tiene un id único.

**Tabla imagen**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS imagen (
    id   INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    nombre_imagen  TEXT
);
```

Con esto estamos diciendo que cada imagen es única, pero nada impide que dos imágenes se llamen igual. Si piensas en un sistema de almacenamiento donde los usuarios pueden subir archivos, de seguro todos los usuarios pueden subir `prueba.jpg` y son archivos distintos con el mismo nombre. Si fuera por ejemplo una colección limitada de avatares donde cada usuario puede elegir el suyo, el modelo cambia. Hay muchos casos de uso y no viene al caso detallar aquí la implementación.

**Tabla atributo** (se llamaba categoría, me parece que es más claro asi)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS atributo (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre_atributo TEXT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT nombre_atributo_unique UNIQUE
);
```

Cada atributo tiene un id único. Su nombre también es único. Lo pienso así como para llenar un selector en una interfaz de usuario en donde le puedas añadir atributos a tu imagen de una lista, pero que esa lista admita añadir atributos que no existen (ejemplo: [usando Select2 con el atributo tags en true](https://select2.org/tagging)). Entonces, por ejemplo, el 1 significa *color* y el 2 significa *dimensiones*. Es un diccionario de tuplas únicas.

**Tabla imagen_atributo** (esta es la tabla que relaciona las dos anteriores)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS imagen_atributo (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  imagen_id int NOT NULL,
  atributo_id int NOT NULL,
  atributo_valor TEXT ,
  UNIQUE KEY (imagen_id, atributo_id) ,
  FOREIGN KEY fk_img (imagen_id) REFERENCES imagen (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY fk_atributo (atributo_id) REFERENCES atributo (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Esta es la tabla que relaciona imagenes, atributos y valores de atributos. 
La tabla imagen_atributo tiene un id único que no significa nada. Perfectamente se podría elegir `(imagen_id, atributo_id)` como llave primaria, pero llaves primarias combinadas (y llaves foráneas combinadas) en mi experiencia es buscarse problemas. De todos modos la tupla (imagen_id,atributo_id) es única. Seguro, si una imagen se borra se borran todos sus atributos (pero no se borran del diccionario de atributos). Si un atributo se borra del diccionario, se borran todos los valores que cada imagen tenía en ese atributo (ej. todas la imágenes pierden su atributo 'color').

Llenamos las tablas:

```
INSERT INTO imagen (nombre_imagen)
    VALUES 
    ('casita.jpg'), -- id = 1
    ('perro.jpg'),  -- id = 2
    ('paisaje.jpg') -- id = 3
;

INSERT INTO atributo (nombre_atributo)
    VALUES 
    ('color'),       -- id=1
    ('dimensiones'), -- id=2
    ('peso')         -- id=3
;

INSERT INTO imagen_atributo (imagen_id, atributo_id, valor_atributo)
    VALUES 
    (1,1,'rojo'), -- id=1
    (2,1,'azul'), -- id=2
    (3,2,'40x40'),-- id=3
    (2,3,'40Kb')  -- id=4
;
```

Entonces, para listar cada atributo de cada imagen:

```
SELECT ia.imagen_id,
       nombre_imagen,
       ia.atributo_id
       nombre_atributo,
       valor_atributo
FROM imagen_atributo ia
     JOIN imagen ON ia.imagen_id = imagen.id
     JOIN atributo ON ia.atributo_id = atributo.id
ORDER BY ia.id
```

Nos daría

```
imagen_id  nombre_imagen atributo_id nombre_atributo valor_atributo
1          casita.jpg    1           color           rojo
2          perro.jpg     1           color           azul
3          paisaje.jpg   2           dimensiones     40x40
2          perro.jpg     3           peso            40Kb
```

Este modelo no es estrictamente tercera forma normal, porque la tabla relación además tiene un valor, pero es la manera más sencilla que se me ocurre de cumplir con los tres postulados del principio.

Comment: Gracias @amenadiel por tu tiempo. Esta solución que das no encaja exactamente en las especificaciones que necesito. Necesito tener los atributos categorizados incluso antes de tener ninguna imagen. Es decir que pueda consultar los colores disponibles, los tamaños disponibles, etc... antes añadir ninguna imagen a la relación.

Comment: Ya veo. Entonces las tablas de categoría y valor están prepobladas. Una de las dos debe llevar el id de la otra para llenar un selector dependiendo de otro