# Diseño circular en una base de datos

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Quiero saber si la relación que establezco entre mis tablas es correcta, o si es incorrecto trabajarlo de esa manera.

La razón por la que la diseñe de esa manera fue por lo siguiente:

```
-----Categoria----
|id | Nombre      |
| 1 | Electronico |
| 2 | Higiene     |


---SubCategoria----
|id | idCategoria | Nombre  |
| 1 |      1      | Laptop  |
| 2 |      1      | Camaras |
| 3 |      1      | Celular |
| 4 |      2      | Jabon   |

------------------Producto--------------------
|id | nombre   | idcategoria | idsubcategoria |
| 1 | Sony Eric|      1      |       3        |
| 2 | Canon    |      1      |       2        |
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Con el id de subcategoría ya tienes la categoría si quieres tener una varias categorías asignadas en varias subcategorías entonces es una tabla categoria_subcategoria, y esa se relacionaria

Comment: ¿Por que  categorías y subcategorias?  ¿Solo dos niveles vas a tener? ¿Y si quieres tener otra categoría en "Celulares" que sea "iphones" y "android"?. ¿Por otro lado, los productos, solo tendrán una sola categoría? Estos temas se han conversado hace un tiempo atras, fijate esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/88076/relaciones-de-tablas-en-mysql/88426#88426

Comment: Tu comentario me sorprendio bastante, y es una opcion interesante que considerare, pero dentro de mi regla de negocio actual(tal vez lo modifique) no lo llegue a considerar. Pero asumiendo que solo necesite dos niveles de categorias, la relacion en la base de datos es correcta? Y la relacion que ambas tienen con la tabla producto estaria bien?

Comment: Las relaciones en una BD deben quedarte de tal forma que no hagan un circulo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a mi modesto entender, yo sacaria la viculacion de la tabla productos con la de categoria, directamente solo tendria con la subcategoria, ya que sabiendo la sub podes llegar a la categoria padre, y no necesitas poner datos repetidos, por que podes tener varias subcategorias de la misma categoria, y si necesitas saber cuan es el padre, directamente consultas sobre el padre de esa subcategoria.
Espero que sea mas o menos claro, sacando eso rompes esa forma circular que mencionas. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Para el caso de categorias y subcategorias pudieras crear una tabla intermedia, que cumpla la condición de muchos a muchos; por lo cual debería tener la siguiente estructura

A manera de ejemplo

```
CREATE TABLE categoria_subcategoria(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_categoria INT NOT NULL,
    id_subcategoria INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_categoria_subcategoria_categoria FOREIGN KEY(id_categoria) REFERENCES categorias(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_categoria_subcategoria_subcategoria FOREIGN KEY(id_subcategoria) REFERENCES subcategorias(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

> Para cumplir la relación de muchos a muchos y en dicha tabla poder
>   guardar los registros

Comment: La relacion que considero entre categorias y subcategorias es de uno a muchos, realmente. Osea una categoria puede tener varias subcategorias. Por lo que cada vez que registro una subcategoria lo relacion con su padre categoria. Por eso lo relaciones con dos tablas. Eso esta mal?
Lo otro es la tabla producto, tiene la id de ambas, por que aunque selecciona la id de una categoria, puede elegeir cualquiera de las subcategorias hijas y guardarlas en su tabla. Es por eso que se forma un circulo, y lei que eso se debe evitar. Por eso pedia una correccion.