# Traer categorias con multiples niveles

Tags: mysql, laravel

Tengo en base de datos una tabla de *categorías* de hasta tres niveles. En ésta guardo sus subcategorías de manera recursiva. La estructura es ésta:

```
    categoria
------------------
(pk) | id
     | nombre
     | slug
     | icono
(fk) | padre      <-- el id de su categoría padre o null si es de nivel 1
```

Las *categorias* de nivel 1 tienen *subcategorías* de nivel 2 y las del nivel 2 tienen *subcategorías* de nivel 3.

```
- 1:  categoria              nivel 1
    - 1001: categoria           nivel 2
        - 1001001: categoria       nivel 3
        - 1001002: categoria       nivel 3
        - 1001003: categoria       nivel 3
    - 1002:categoria            nivel 2
        - 1002001: categoria       nivel 3
        - 1002002: categoria       nivel 3
        - 1002003: categoria       nivel 3
```

Modelo de **`Categoria`**

```
class Categoria extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [ 'nombre', 'nivel', 'icono', 'padre', 'slug' ];

    public function subcategorias() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Categoria', 'padre');
    }

}
```

Intento traer a mi vista todas estas categorias de la manera más eficiente posible, por el momento hago lo siguiente:

En **`CategoriaController`**

```
$categorias1 = Categoria::where('nivel', 1)
                          ->with('subcategorias.subcategorias')
                          ->get();
```

Según Laravel estoy haciendo [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), haciendo solamente tres queries para traer toda esa data, en lugar de hacer una query por cada categoría.

Ahora bien, a pesar de tener mi tabla indexada y usar *eager loading*, quisiera que el traer esta data respondiera mucho más rapido.

En [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) uno puede traer un datos anidados en json usando las funciones *array_to_json*, *array_agg*, *row_to_json* ([véase esta pregunta como referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137237/postgres-nested-json-array-using-row-to-json)) para luego indexarlos a la vista mediante javascript.

**Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de hacer algo similar con [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) para traer toda los datos que necesito en una sola query o de que otra forma podría hacer para traer mucho más rapido mis datos.**

---

*Tecnologías:*
*- Laravel 5.4*
*- Mysql 5.6*

Comment: Recuerdo haber respondido en un caso muy parecido, pero a nivel de MySQL, no tenía nada que ver con Laravel. Mi propuesta consistía si mal no recuerdo en una sola tabla con las categorías y otra que manejase los niveles.

Comment: [Este es el caso al que me refería en mi comentario anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/88081/29967). Hay también una respuesta de Patricio que es interesante. Dejo el enlace por si te puede servir en algo.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano, revisare las respuestas

Comment: @A.Cedano, gracias por compartirme el enlace, sin embargo yo ya tengo mi tabla estructurada de manera parecida a la que proponen, guardo categorias y su subcategorias dentro de una misma tabla con relaciones recursivas y las tengo codificadas de manera similar a lo que propone Patricio, solo que un poquito mas optimizado; pero mi cuestion es mas que todo sobre traerme todas las categorias y sus subcategorias y las subcategorias de estas de la manera mas optima posible, hasta ahora tengo el avance que he mostrado, pero queria saber si a nivel de mysql o laravel hay algo mejor

Comment: Lo solucionaste de alguna manera? yo lo hubiese almacenado en cache...2 años después jajajajjaaj

Answer (score 0):

Puedes retornar todos las categorías de nivel 1 (Padre = null). En tu modelo creas una función hijos, y le colocas que retorne los hijos de un padre.

```
public function hijos()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Categoria','id','padre');
}
```

Y cuando quieras mostrar en tu view los hijos de una categoría solo haces:

```
@forearch($categorias as $categoria)
  @foreach($categoria->hijos as $hijo)
      {{ $hijo}}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

También puedes retornar todas los padres con sus hijos:

```
$categorias = Categoria::all()->with('hijos')
                          ->get();
```

Comment: Gracias por responder @Alex, pero lo que sugieres en tu respuesta y lo he hecho, y esta en los detalles de la pregunta, lo que necesitaba era optimizar aun mas la traida de datos, pero de todas formas gracias