# Base de datos con productos, categorías de productos y diferentes atributos (mysql)

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo una tabla **Producto(id_producto, nombre, id_categoria)**; una tabla **categoria(id_categoria, nombre_categoria)** si agregara registros quedaría asi:

**TABLA CATEGORIA:**

id_categoria = 1, nombre_categoria = smartphone

id_categoria = 2, nombre_categoria = laptop

**TABLA PRODUCTO:**

id_producto = 1, nombre = iGal 7S, categoria = 1

id_producto = 2, nombre = notebookPro, categoria = 2

Pero, el problema es el siguiente: cada categoría tiene otros atributos propios. Por ejemplo: para la categoría Smartphone yo necesito registrar caracteristicas propias de un smarphone como **(tamaño de pantalla, ram, memoria interna, tipo_bateria, SO, version del SO, IMEI, etc.)** y para la categoria laptop **(disco duro, ram, procesador, motherboard, pantalla, targ. video, teclado, etc.)**.

Entonces no puedo solo crear una tabla categoría asociada con la tabla producto porque necesito registrar esos atributos para cada categoría. Se me ocurre crear una tabla para registrar los atributos de cada categoría, por ejemplo: tabla **atributo_smartphone** y otra tabla **atributo_laptop** pero imagínense que hubieran 20 0 mas categorías, tendría que crear 20 tablas y eso creo que no es la manera de resolver el problema. ¿que debo hacer?.

Comment: La manera apropriada es para crear una tabla por cada categoria, como lo que dice. Tambien hay otra alternativa, es almacenar todas las caracteristicas de un producto en una cadena json, y guardalo en solo una columna de tabla Productos. Sin embargo, si usa json, tiene que hacer _parsing_ el json si quiere extraer las caracteristicas.

Comment: Quizá [la solución planteada aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/88081/29967) te podría servir para este caso (sólo interesaría la primera parte de la respuesta). Puedes ver allí también la respuesta aceptada, y la respuesta de Patricio así como la pregunta y los diferentes comentarios, para entender un poco el contexto en que se llegó a esa propuesta de solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente hayan varias formas de resolverlo, cada una con ventajas y desventajas. La que es mejor para ti dependerá del uso final que vayas a hacer.

Una de las maneras que se me ocurre es hacer una tabla general de atributos como en el siguiente ejemplo (Ojo!, la sintaxis es de **MySQL**) (que podrás revisar mejor [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf7032/11):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MT_categorias` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `MT_categorias` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES
  ('1', 'smartphone'),
  ('2', 'laptop');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MT_productos` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fk_categoria` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `MT_productos` (`id`, `fk_categoria`, `nombre`) VALUES
  ('1', '1',  'iGal 7S'),
  ('2', '2', 'notebookPro');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MT_atributos` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fk_categoria` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `unidades` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `MT_atributos` (`id`, `fk_categoria`, `nombre`, `unidades`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'tamaño pantalla', 'pulgadas'),
  ('2', '1', 'RAM', 'GB'),
  ('3', '1', 'tipo bateria', ''),
  ('4', '1', 'SO', ''),
  ('5', '2', 'HHDD', 'GB'),
  ('6', '2', 'RAM', 'GB'),
  ('7', '2', 'velocidad procesador', 'GHz'),
  ('8', '2', 'SO', '');

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RL_atributos_producto` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fk_producto` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fk_atributo` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `valor` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `RL_atributos_producto` (`id`, `fk_producto`, `fk_atributo`, `valor`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', '1', '5'),
  ('2', '1', '2', 'GB'),
  ('3', '1', '3', 'Ion Litio'),
  ('4', '1', '4', 'Android');
```

Aunque en el modelo no lo he hecho, con este esquema y para simplificar, yo trataría la categoría como un atributo más.

Algún ejemplo de las consultas que deberías utilizar con el modelo anterior serian:

```
-- Atributos de una categoria:
SELECT c.nombre, a.nombre
FROM `MT_categorias` c
INNER JOIN `MT_atributos` a
ON c.id = a.fk_categoria;

-- Atributos de un producto concreto:
SELECT p.nombre, a.nombre, ap.valor, a.unidades 
FROM `RL_atributos_producto` ap
INNER JOIN `MT_productos` p
ON ap.fk_producto = p.id
INNER JOIN `MT_atributos` a
ON ap.fk_atributo = a.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra alternativa viendo tu problematica, es crear una tabla Caracteristica(id, descripcion)->1, ram; 2, procesador. Y otra tabla intermedia para relacionar Producto con esta nueva tabla CarateristicaProducto(idProducto, idCaracteristica, valor)-> 1, 1, 2GB; 2, 1, 16GB