# Reordenar la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Hace unos dias hice una pregunta en la cual tengo una base de datos asi:

Productos

```
id(int) producto(varchar)   valor(varchar)  fechap(date)    fechal(int)
1       Pan Lactal          150             2020-02-01      15
2       Harina              75              2020-02-11      30
3       Aceite              150             2020-02-28      15
4       Fideos              80              2020-03-01      30
```

Lo cual ahora se agrega la columna `categoria`.

```
id(int) categoria(varchar) producto(varchar)   valor(varchar)  fechap(date)    fechal(int)
1       panificados        Pan Lactal          150             2020-02-01      15
2       almacen            Harina              75              2020-02-11      30
3       almacen            Aceite              150             2020-02-28      15
4       almacen            Fideos              80              2020-03-01      30
```

En la lista de producto figura un enlace son las categorias:

```
<a href="srvs/productos.php?cate=<?=$rowl['categoria'];?>">Almacen</a>
```

Cada categoria tiene una subcategoria, como por ejemplo: dentro de `almacen` puede esta la subcategoria `legumbres`.

Estoy tomando ejemplor de tiendas virtuales que tambien funcionan asi, pero me estoy volviendo loca y no se como ordenar las subcategorias dentro de las categorias y no se como hacerlo y estoy confundida y no se si tengo que hacer un bucle o algo.

Me podrian orientar como puedo hacerlo? Gracias

Comment: Hace un tiempo hubo una pregunta aquí muy trabajada con esto de las categorías. La respuesta que yo propuse responde precisamente a un modelo que incluye categorías principales (padre) y sub-categorias (hijos), [te dejo aquí el enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/88081/29967) por si te puede ayudar. En cuanto a las dos tablas que muestras, no sé si estoy interpretando mal, pero veo redundancia entre las dos tablas ¿?

Comment: Son la misma tabla, los que pasa es que agrege la fila `categoria` y si mal no entiendo, leyendo un poco el link que me pasate, `categoria` es el padre y `producto` seria el hijo. Ahora voy a probar como lo reflejo con php. Gracias!

Comment: @A.Cedano una consulta, tengo que crear otra tabla? como listo las categorias fuera del listado del productos?

Comment: No entendí bien eso de que *`categoría` es el padre y `producto` sería el hijo*. Entonces no estamos hablando de categorías y sub-categorías, sino de tablas relacionadas que sería otra cosa. Puede que, sea como sea, necesites por una lado una tabla `producto`, luego una tabla `categoria` y una tercer tabla `categoria_producto` para mantener las relaciones (por sus ID) evitando así redundancia de datos.

Comment: Quiero listar las categorias y agruparlar, no los productos porque puedos pasarlos por GET y listo

Comment: No entiendo mucho lo que me quieres decir sobre GET. Si tienes bases de datos relacionales puedes obtener cualquier dato basándote en las relaciones.

Comment: Mil disculpas. Lo tengo que hacer es listar las categorias y dentro de esas categorias hay subcategorias, como lo hacen las tiendas online. En la categoria almacen habra; aceite, harina, legumbres, etc. Lo que yo hice en la base de datos fue agregar la fila `categoria` y ahi fue con se me hizo una nube

Comment: Ya, pero tu confusión es *conceptual* primeramente. Una cosa es un `producto` (aceite, harina, camisa, teléfono), y otra cosa es una `categoría` (alimentos, ropa, tecnologia, electrodomésticos). No sé si me entiendes esa parte. Por ejemplo, `almacen` ni siquiera sería una categoría. Si quieres no perderte en el diseño, piénsalo como en la realidad ¿no? un `almacén` es un lugar.

Comment: Claro, bueno, voy a probar a ver que me sale y modifico la pregunta. Gracias

Comment: Cuando programas y diseñas modelos de datos ayuda mucho pensarlo como en la vida real: **`productos`**: aceite, pescado, pan, vino, ajo, camisa, tv, lavadora; **`categorias`**: alimentos, bebidas, ropa, electrodomésticos; **`sub-categorias`**: vegetales, cárnicos, del mar, marisco, condimentos, ropa deportiva, ropa de vestir, hi-tech, hogar ... etc. Por ejemplo, un mismo producto podría estar en varios rangos de categorías y podría haber sub-sub categorías, por ejemplo (alimentos->cárnicos->[bovino, porcino]), todo depende de lo que quieras hacer.

Comment: Si entiendo, lo estoy apuntando a lo que me decis a ver que sale. En todo caso modificara la pregunta, Gracias por la ayuda Cedano

Comment: No hay problema, puedes modificar la pregunta cuando lo consideres oportuno para indicar lo que llevas hecho y qué dificultades tienes. Saludos.