# Mostrar productor por categorias

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo una página en mi web para todos los productos por cada una de las categorías que tengo en la base de datos. Tengo dos tablas, una contiene id y nombre de las categorías, y otra tabla con los productos y una `foreign key` de `id_categoria`.

Mediante *PHP*, quiero que me muestre la categoría y debajo todos los productos en ella, cando no haya más productos, que pase a la siguiente categoría.

El problema es que me muestra la misma categoría por el número de productos que hay.

Sentencia SQL:

```
"SELECT producto.id_producto, producto.producto, categoria.id_categoria,
categoria.categoria FROM productos INNER JOIN categoria ON
categoria.id_categoria = producto.id_categoria"
```

Código PHP:

```
<?php
    include_once 'data.php';
    $artists = getProductos();
    $size = sizeof($productos);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        echo "<button type='button' class='collapsible'>" . $productos[$i]["categoria"] . "</button>";
        echo "<div class='content'>";
        for ($k = 0; $k < $size; $k++) {
            echo "<a>• " . $productos[$k]["producto"] . "</a></br>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

Resultado:

```
ROPA
pantalon 
camisa 
arroz
COMIDA
pantalon 
camisa 
arroz
```

Comment: Sin ver la consulta SQL y pequeño set de resultados será complicado poder ayudarte.

Comment: @A.Cedano la consulta seria la siguiente: "SELECT producto.id_producto, producto.producto, categoria.id_categoria, categoria.categoria 
  FROM productos
  INNER JOIN categoriaON categoria.id_categoria = producto.id_categoria"

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y agrégala a la pregunta. Así como un ejemplo de los resultados que obtienes.

Comment: Podrías hacer una consulta que te agrupe los datos, empezando por categorías, y luego los productos que hay en ella, luego sería relativamente sencillo mostrar los datos al leerlos. [Revisa esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/88081/29967), observa la primera consulta que hay en ella y el ejemplo de datos que salen separados por comas. Creo que es algo parecido lo que quieres aquí.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que necesitas hacer es ordenar los productos por categoría y después por producto. Para este ejemplo, se van a usar los nombres, ambos en forma ascendente (por defecto):

```
SELECT producto.id_producto, producto.producto, categoria.id_categoria,
categoria.categoria FROM productos
INNER JOIN categoria ON categoria.id_categoria = producto.id_categoria
ORDER BY categoria.categoria, producto.producto
```

Con esto, vas a obtener algo como:

```
COMIDA - arroz
ROPA - camisa
ROPA - pantalon
```

Actualmente tienes dos ciclos recorriendo todos los resultados, sin identificar a qué categoría pertenecen los productos. Se necesita solo un ciclo y una variable para comparar cuál fue la última categoría que se mostró y, con base en eso, agregar botón o no.

```
<?php
    include_once 'data.php';
    $artists = getProductos();
    $size = sizeof($productos);

    // Crear variable para saber cuál fue la última categoría mostrada
    // Se asigna una cadena vacía para poder mostrar la primera categoría
    $categoria = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        // ¿La categoría actual es diferente de la anterior?
        if($productos[$i]['categoria'] != $categoria) {
            // Si la última categoría no es cadena vacía
            if($categoria != '') {
                // Cerrar contenedor
                echo "</div>";
            }
            // Mostrar botón
            echo "<button type='button' class='collapsible'>" . $productos[$i]["categoria"] . "</button>";
            // Crear contenedor
            echo "<div class='content'>";
            // Actualizar última categoría
            $categoria = $producto[$i]['categoria'];
        }
        // Mostrar producto
        echo "<a>• " . $productos[$i]["producto"] . "</a></br>";
    }
    // Si la última categoría no es cadena vacía
    if($categoria != '') {
        // Quedó un contenedor abierto, hay que cerrarlo
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

Rsultado:

```
COMIDA
* arroz
ROPA
* camisa
* pantalon
```

Seguramente hay mejores formas de lograr este resultado, pero esta es una forma simple y fácil de entender.