# Obtener las IDs de todos los descendientes en Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

Tengo una jerarquía de categorías, donde una categoría puede tener 0, 1 o más hijas y cada una de estas hijas lo mismo.
La relación entre las categorías es refléxiva, de 1 a N.

Mysql:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `shop_categories` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `level` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `parent_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Necesitaría un modo eficiente de obtener para una categoría las IDs de todas las categorías descendientes, es decir de sus hijas y las hijas de sus hijas hasta que ya no haya más descendientes.

La función que uso actualmente requiere mucha memoria.
A la categoría dada le asigno un nivel 0, a sus hijas el nivel 1, sus IDs las añado a los descendientes luego recorro cada una de ellas asignando las IDs de sus hijos a un nivel 2, y así sucesivamente...

Estoy trabajando con PHP y Laravel / Eloquent.

> Editado

Hice una mejora significativa en base a dos funciones. La función principal, voy a llamarla `getDescendantIds()` recibe la ID de la categoría de la que se quiere obtener sus descendientes y una secundaria que recibe una ID de categoría y devuelve las IDs de sus hijos y llamé `getChildrenIds()`, que funciona en base a la query: `SELECT id FROM shop_categories WHERE parent_id = ' . $categoryId`.
En la primera uso dos arrays, uno `$output` en donde voy metiendo cada uno de los descendientes (IDs) y devolveré al final y otro `$temp` donde se guardan temporalmente y voy recorriendo con un `while` obteniendo los hijos de cada una de sus IDs para añadirlos al mismo array al tiempo que esa ID pasa al de salida. En el momento en que el array `$temp` queda vació se ha completado la jerarquía.
Va muy rápido con un par de miles de categorías, el problema lo veo que la cantidad de llamadas que se realizan a `getChildrenIds`, y por tanto consultas.

Voy a probar a reducir el número de *queries* pasando las IDs de los padres en bloque, es decir, que cada vez que obtenga un grupo de IDs hijas, obtengo todas sus hijas y las meto a `$temp` al tiempo que muevo en bloque todas las IDs que use en la query, la modificación sería que `getChildrenIds` recibiera un array de IDs y la consulta fuera: `SELECT id FROM shop_categories WHERE parent_id IN (' . $strCategoryIds . ')'`.
Creo que esto reduce las consultas de una por ID de descendiente a una por cada grupo de IDs hijas obtenidas.

> He de destacar que ***esta pregunta*** esta motivada por un **cuello de botella** debido a la implementación original del método que obtenía los descendientes, por lo que ***busca formas eficientes de obtener las IDs de los descendientes.***

Comment: Creo que [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/88081/29967) puede ser útil para tu caso.

Comment: Se me ocurre que al crear/editar una categoria podrías buscar todos sus ancestros y guardarlo en una tabla aparte, por ejemplo, `categories_ancestors (id, ancestor_id)`. De esta forma podrías saber rápidamente saber TODOS los acentros de una categoría, como también todos sus descendientes.

Comment: También podrías mostrar tu codigo de Eloquent, ya que entiendo que necesitas mejorar allí. Por otra parte, la implementacion de relaciones de Eloquent ya es muy eficiente de por sí, quizás lo que necesitas es saber como ajustar tu codigo y con eso estarás resuelto.

Comment: La respuesta la quieres en un ¿script de `mysql`? o ¿ en codigo `php`? por que  lo que pides es `recursividad`

Comment: `A. Cedano` la respuesta que enlazas parece interesante, debo analizarla más a fondo.

Comment: @Orici, sería bueno que agregues el código desarrollado. Mejoras que podrías implementar. Crear una única vez la sentencia preparada y reutilizarla cada vez que llamas a la función. Crear un hashmap por cada cada categoría ya analizada para evitar volver a analizar algo previamente obtenido.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de continuar debes informarte sobre la [recursividad/Recursión](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursi%C3%B3n_(ciencias_de_computaci%C3%B3n))

Dicho esto  debes pintar todo el arbol de familiar de un `id` de la tabla `shop_categories`

Este es un ejemplo:

```
function obtenerArrayHijos($id){
    $arrayHijos=array($id);

    $query = "SELECT id from shop_categories where parent_id in ($Nclasific)";
    //echo($query."<br />\n");


     //DEBES CAMBIAR ESTA LINEA POR TU CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS
    $enlaceHost = getEnlaceHost();
  

    $sentencia = mysqli_prepare($enlaceHost,$query);
    if ($sentencia === false) echo(mysqli_error($enlaceHost));

    mysqli_stmt_execute($sentencia);
    $resultado = mysqli_stmt_get_result($sentencia);

    while ($row=$resultado->fetch_array()) {
        array_push($arrayHijos,$row[0]);
        $arrayHijos=array_merge($arrayHijos,obtenerArrayHijos($row[0],$Nactivo));
    }
    return (array_values(array_unique($arrayHijos)));
}
```

Glosario de funciones

`array_values` : Devuelve todos los valores de un array  [url documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-values.php)

`array_unique` : Elimina valores duplicados de un array [url documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique.php)

`array_merge` : Combina dos o más arrays [url documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php)

`array_push` ; agrega un elemento al array  [url documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php)